# プロパティが初期化されない。

Tags: swift

お世話になっております。
以下で落ちる原因がわかりません。

```
class MapsDocument: UIDocument {

    var documentText : NSString? {

        get {
            return self.documentText　// 【ここで落ちる】
        }

        set(newText) {
            let oldText = self.documentText
            self.documentText = newText!.copy() as? NSString

            // 取り消し操作を登録する
            self.undoManager.setActionName("Text Change")
            self.undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: "setDocumentText:", object: oldText)
        }
    }
```

として、他のビューコントローラーで、

```
    var _document : MapsDocument!

        override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
            let newText = self.textView.text

            if _document != nil {

                _document.documentText = newText // 【ここで落ちる】

                // ドキュメントを閉じる
                _document.closeWithCompletionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
```

として呼び出すと落ちます。

何がいけないのでしょうか？

`documentText`が`nil`なようなのですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

計算型プロパティ（**Computed Property**）の、**get**、**set**文の使い方を間違えています。`get`、`set`内で、プロパティ自身の値を参照するのは、コンパイルエラーにはなりませんが、論理矛盾なのはあきらかです。（Optional（`!`、`?`）の使い方も、ちょっとあやしい）
こういうケースでは、Computed Propertyではなく、プロパティオブザーバ（**Property Observer**）を使うのが、妥当だと思います。

```
var documentText: String = "" {
    // 初期値を与えておけば、オプショナルにしなくてすむ。
    didSet {
        // 取り消し操作を登録する
        self.undoManager.setActionName("Text Change")
        self.undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: "setDocumentText:", object: (oldValue as NSString))
        // didSet内では、変更前の値をoldValueで取得できる。
    }
}
```

※`String`型と`NSString`型は、`as`でキャスト可能。
（Undo Managerの使い方は、検証に時間がかかるので、正しいか確認していません）